# Fonts with common glyphs/char sizes

Tags: fonts, size, width, monospace

I know there are monospaced fonts that have the same width per character, but they don't solve my problem.

I'm looking for a pair (or more) of fonts that have common glyph sizes.

I expect that if I write any string using font A with size *x*, it will have the same width as if I write it using font B with same size.

Do such fonts exist? Do you know any?

Comment: You haven't said anything about how similar or different the fonts should be. You may be able to find fonts with "duplexed" weights --- different weights but same widths. (Cf https://fonts.google.com/knowledge/glossary/multiplexed_duplexed_uniwidth.)

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Windows, the Bahnschrift variable font is "duplexed", meaning that the different weights have the same widths.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/bahnschrift